# What does "function anonymous" mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

I was fooling around with JS a bit, and I found this:

[image]

Anyone care to explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An anonymous function is one that doesn't have a name. For example, you can do:

```
(function(){ alert("Hello World!") })();
```

This creates a function with no name and immediately calls it. If the code caused an exception to be raised, the JavaScript runtime will report a failure in an anonymous function.

Also, functions are themselves objects with a class named `Function`. You can use this class to define a new function like this (instead of the built-in syntax):

```
(new Function("x", "y", "return x+y"))(1, 2);
```

This is pretty much the same as writing:

```
(function(x, y) { return x + y })(1, 2);
```

This gives you a peek into the object-oriented nature of JavaScript's functions.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the `Function()` function (which is a constructor of `Function` objects) it returns you a function. Functions created dynamically in that way have no name, and so the name "anonymous" is given to it.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Comment: `+1` - Functions bound to HTML elements are also anonymous.  For example, if you had `<a id="foo" onclick="window.alert(123);">` and looked at `foo.onclick` under a debugger, you'd get the same thing.

Comment: If I do `Function('test')`, I receive: `function anonymous() {
test
}`. This still returns function with name `anonymous`. Last argument is body of the function, all arguments before it are function arguments.

Comment: Your argument 'test' specifies the code body of the function. There is no (standard) way to set the name of the function as seen in the debugger.

Comment: Yea @Tadeck is correct - The `Function` constructor does not have a parameter for the name of the function.  It always returns a reference to an anonymous function.

Comment: I wouldn't say the name "anonymous" is *given* to it. If it was, the following code wouldn't give a ReferenceError... `Function('alert(anonymous)')();` It's displayed with that name, but the function doesn't actually *have* the name.

Comment: This is wrong.  That link doesn't mention the word anonymous, the `.name` property defined by SpiderMonkey does not have the value `anonymous`, there is no binding `anonymous` defined when control enters the function body, and anonymous functions defined by other methods (e.g. `function () {}`) do not have that name in their `toString` output.

Comment: @MikeSamuel - the purpose of the link was merely to document the constructor being called by the OP. So it ain't wrong.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker.  It is wrong, and the link provides no support for your claims.

Answer (score 1):

It is a quirk in the way multiple browsers' implementations of `Function.prototype.toString` renders functions created via the `Function` constructor, but it is not significant and it does not appear in any version of the EcmaScript specification.

Normally a named function

```
function anonymous(x) {
  if (x) {
    alert('hi');
  } else {
    anonymous(!x);
  }
}
```

will `alert` regardless of the value passed in, because the name of the function can be used to call it recursively (modulo IE bugs), but that is not the case with the `anonymous` created via `new Function`.

```
(new Function('x', 'if (x) alert("hi"); else anonymous(!x);'))(false)
```

fails with an error.

Comment: +1 for *"It is a quirk...it is not significant and it does not appear in any version of the EcmaScript specification"*. `Function(); anonymous(); // ReferenceError`

Answer (score 0):

An anonymous function is a function with no name. They aren't specific to Javascript, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function

For JS, basically instead of this:

```
function myFunc() { }
```

you can do:

```
var myFunc = function() { }
```

Comment: -1 Please look again into the question - you will see that the question is about `function anonymous() {` from the console - see the screenshot OP included.